# CSS border causes scrollspy bug.

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Intro
I'm trying to make this bootstrap layout with a full height left-side navigation and a partial width fixed header. The left nav utilizes scrollspy.js. So far, so good.(Note: this is intended for desktop screens so far.)

http://www.bootply.com/L2AQ0jXmYS

When I added border-left style to the pills in the left-side nav, it starts acting wonky. Once you click on a scrollspy link and jump to a section, you cannot scroll out of that section.

To reproduce the bug (Tested in Chrome Mac v.46.0 and Safari Mac v.9.0)

1. First,manually scroll through the main content area. You will notice
   that the left-nav scroll-spy properly causes the highlight to follow
   the content shown on the screen.
2. Next click on one of the links in
   the left nav to jump to a section.
3. Now try to manually scroll
   through the main content area again. You will notice that you cannot
   leave the section you are in. The scroll keeps returning you to this
   area.

If I edit the CSS and remove the border on the left of the active pill, it works properly. I cannot understand why.

Comment: It is kinda weird. If this of any help: http://www.bootply.com/dtA2lnJamP If you add same width invisible border to the `li a` inactive state, it fixes the issue. Looks like the `active` class does not get toggled if it has a border. Not sure why without seeing what's happening in scollspy.

Comment: Thanks Zealander. That's one thing I thought I tried but apparently not. Much appreciated!